# Can not export IPA file from XCode 6.1

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, iphone-developer-program, xcode6.1

I've wasted a day trying to export IPA file using development profiles. I'm a developer since 18 months now. And its not something that i don't know about exporting IPA. And i really hate Apple developers for changing the way we used to export a simple IPA. I've already exported hundreds of times but this time i'm having no luck.

I think what is needed to export a successful IPA requires these things to be available in the system

1. Private key with Certificate in Keychain -> Login -> My Certificates
2. Login in with developer account in XCode -> Preferences -> Accounts
3. Archive the project and select Export -> Save for Ad Hoc Deployment -> Select developer account from the list.
4. Wait until XCode does some magic. (This is the part where XCode fails everytime. See attached screenshot please)

[image]

**Here's what i've tried**:

1. Removing all keychain certificates and provisioning profiles. - **DIDN'T WORKED**
2. Restart XCode and System (Almost 3 times) - **DIDN'T WORKED**
3. Removing certificates and provisioning profiles from Apple developer portal and regenerate all of them. - **DIDN'T WORKED**
4. Tried AirSign / Testflight. - **DIDN'T WORKED**

**HINT: I am using XCode 6.1.1 GM SEED and previously had installed along with XCode 6.2 beta. But i removed XCode 6.2 Beta later**

Someone please tell me where i'm going wrong.. Thanks...

Comment: are you making your IPA with development certificate? Means with developer certificate and profile?

Comment: Can you try with installing your distribution certificate and profile both before create IPA with developer profile? I faced this issue sometime and it works for me with this way. Check If this way it work for you.

Comment: Ya. Sure. Will update you in a while. Thanks. @Nikunj

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: As per the screenshot

Comment: I just encountered this and think it's because we jumped on XCode 6.1.1 which seems unavailable to get anymore.  And of course is looked upon as "Beta" from iTunes Connect.  My guess is it's Apple's inconsistency and fault.  Even the App Store doesn't recognize it and wants me to downgrade.  I'll wait it out a bit, otherwise have to re-instal 6.1 again.

Comment: @SebastianDwornik, Actually i have multiple developer accounts under different names, the problem is with one account only.!!

Comment: Have you resolved the issue?

Comment: @Imran check the accepted answer. It was the error of distribution certificate, i did not had it installed on my machine. I created it and installed distribution certificates and boom.. it works like charm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Starting from XCode 6, you have to generate an **AdHoc** type cerificate from the Apple Developer Center to be able to save the **.ipa** for AdHoc deployment. I was also facing the same issue and generated a new certificate particularly for **AdHoc Distribution**. Archiving using that resolved the issue.

Comment: Thanks for being quick. Let me try the solution.

Comment: And do you mean that i have to generate certificate by selecting "App Store and Ad Hoc"?

Comment: But i want to create IPA for development only, not distribution.

Comment: I understand that but according to the new rules or definition (or whatever), your build will have to be signed as **AdHoc** even for development and internal testing purposes. baffling, since XCode 5 presented no such issues. I did some research on this when I first faced the issue and could find no other way. Hence, try generating and using a new AdHoc certificate.

Comment: Having the same error just in one dev account, not in other dev accounts. Doing the same thing in other dev accounts and it works the same way.

Comment: Sorry buddy, no idea then.

Comment: @jalakpatel create distribution certificate & provisioning profile and install it on your machine.

Comment: Unfortunately no. In XCode > 6, IPA is signed using distribution certificate, (as per what i see on export dialog), so you have to install it @jalakpatel

Comment: not, working for me , i got same  message "you have a valid distribution certificate in member center , but not installed locally.  if your signing identity installed on another mac, you export developer profile on that mac and import it on this mac . you can revoke current certificate and request new one "

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you using the fastlane tools to handle every aspects of code signing and ipa generation.

The cert command allows you to create a new certificate as needed : no option for distribution certificate, --developement for a development one.

The sigh command allows you to create a new provisionning profile : no options = app store, --adhoc = ad hoc, --development = development

The gym command allows you build ipa, same options as above !

Meanwhile there's a trick for dev ipa generation :
    - set your code signing assets as needed for development in Xcode target

1. build the app for a device
2. Go to te "Product" group folder in Xcode files navigator
3. Ctrl-click on yourApp.app and click "Show in finder"
4. Copy the .app in a new folder called "Payload"
5. Create a zip from this folder using Ctrl+click, archive
6. Rename this archive as yourApp.ipa

You're now able to install this dev signed ipa over the air or through iTunes on the devices recorded in the provisionning profile used to build the app.

Answer (score 0):

You will not get this issues if you create certificated through xcode.

xcode->Preferences->Select Apple id->select account->view details->click on plus button

Useing this certificate revoke your provisioning profile then again

xcode->Preferences->Select Apple id->select account->view details-> click on refresh button

Now you will not get this error

Comment: one simple thing open xocde 5 and export build from there, it works

Comment: It works, but it is a workaround. I need a straight way.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing your distribution certificate and profile before creating IPA with developer profile. I faced this issue and that fixed it.